# Cross-platform backup solutions

Tags: linux, windows, macos, backup, cross-platform

Here's my situation. I'm always feeling uncomfortable with backups which are bound to one specific OS. A Mac OS X Time Machine backup, for example, is not very helpful when you can't afford a new Mac after your old one broke down.

So, what I'm looking for is a simple cross-platform backup software which can be used on Linux, Windows and Mac OS X. It's important to me that I can always plug my external HDD into any machine and access every file and folder on it instantly.

Favored features would be:

- scheduled backups
- incremental backups
- easy to use (at least easier than Clonezilla)

Thanks, Simon

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_backup_software for a list where versions for Windows, OS X and Linux exist.

Answer (score 2):

Use the tool [BackIt](https://code.google.com/p/backit/).

> It is not a professional backup tool, it only helps those users who
>   want to backup/copy some files and folders to a USB or CD/DVD
>   routinely. We have covered similar backup tools before, SimpleBackup,
>   SyncToy, and FileMove Lite are all equally good.

[image]

It works on `Windows`, `Linux`, and `Mac` provided you have A[dobe Air](http://get.adobe.com/air/) installed. If you are looking for free professional backup solution then have a look at Duplicati and FileMyster, both are outstanding.

Features:

- Automatic copy for scheduled archiving.
- Simple and user friendly one window, no complicated stuff archiving.
- Batch copy solution.

Demo video: `http://youtube.com/watch?v=rPNw4UOCJbk`

Comment: A file-by-file (or folder) backup program is indeed the logical way to go because the OPs wish for cross-platform compatibility means it's only worth backing up cross-platform files.